# How to get old value from an entity without implicit update

Tags: hibernate, stripes

I have a user form.

I would like to compare the new password value from that form with the password already saved in DB from the same user when the user submit the form.

But When I try to get the current user data from the DB (findByUniqueKey), it update the password field with the new value before retrieving it.

So my question is: How can I get the old password in db ?

Thanks a lot

Here is my simplified controller:

```
public class UserActionBean {
  @SpringBean
  private UserDAO userDAO;
  private User currentUser;
  private User parentUser;

  @Before(stages = LifecycleStage.BindingAndValidation)
  public void preView() {
    [...]
    parentUser = userDAO.findByUniqueKey("login", getContext().getAuthentication().getLogin());
    [...]
  }

  @HandlesEvent("updateUser")
  public Resolution addUser() {
    [...]
  }

  @ValidationMethod(on = {"updateUser"})
  public void checkForm(ValidationErrors errors) {
    User oldUser = userDAO.findByUniqueKey("login", currentUser.getLogin());
    if (oldUser.getPassword().equals(currentUser.getPassword())) {
      // oldUser password is the same as the currentUser password
      // Even if currentUser password is changed at submission.
    }
  }

  // getters / Setters
}
```

Comment: How could we tell how to fix your code without seeing any single line of it?

Comment: @JBNizet I just updated the post by adding some code. But Im not sure that my issue is specific to my code, but lets see.